# Java.io.IOException: Not connected will be reported when sending SMS using openSMPP lib

Tags: smpp

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/test")
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "GET", value = "测试apo", notes = "")
public void testMail(@RequestParam(name = "host", required = false) String host,
                     @RequestParam(name = "port", required = false) String port,
                     @RequestParam(name = "userName", required = false) String userName,
                     @RequestParam(name = "password", required = false) String password,
                     @RequestParam(name = "phonenumber", required = false) String phonenumber,
                     @RequestParam(name = "verifyCode", required = false) String verifyCode
) {
    log.info("start to send sms notification, reciever,host {},port {}, userName {} password {} destinations is {} verifyCode {}", host, port, userName, password, phonenumber, verifyCode);
    try {
        TCPIPConnection connection = new TCPIPConnection(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
        Session session = new Session(connection);
        BindRequest request = new BindTransmitter();
        request.setSystemId(userName);
        request.setPassword(password);
        //SMPP protocol version
        request.setInterfaceVersion((byte) 0x34);
        session.bind(request);
        String content = "[Registration]" + verifyCode + " is your verification code. Valid in 15 minutes. Please do not share this code with anyone else.";
        SubmitSM submitSM = constructRequest(phonenumber, content);
        SubmitSMResp response = session.submit(submitSM);
        String result = new String(response.toString());
        log.info("send sms notification result is {}", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("invoke sms session exception", e);
    }

}

private SubmitSM constructRequest(String phoneNumber,String content) throws WrongLengthOfStringException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String recipientPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;

    SubmitSM request = new SubmitSM();
    request.setDestAddr(createAddress(recipientPhoneNumber));
    request.setShortMessage(content,Data.ENC_UTF8);
    request.setReplaceIfPresentFlag((byte) 0);
    request.setEsmClass((byte) 0);
    request.setProtocolId((byte) 0);
    request.setPriorityFlag((byte) 0);
    request.setRegisteredDelivery((byte) 1);// we want delivery reports
    request.setDataCoding((byte) 0);
    request.setSmDefaultMsgId((byte) 0);
    return request;
}

private Address createAddress(String address) throws WrongLengthOfStringException {
    Address addressInst = new Address();
    // national ton
    addressInst.setTon((byte) 5);
    // numeric plan indicator
    addressInst.setNpi((byte) 0);
    addressInst.setAddress(address, Data.SM_ADDR_LEN);
    return addressInst;
}
```

**Here is the exception message**

```
java.io.IOException: Not connected
    at org.smpp.TCPIPConnection.send(TCPIPConnection.java:340) ~[opensmpp-core-3.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.smpp.Transmitter.send(Transmitter.java:69) ~[opensmpp-core-3.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.smpp.Session.send(Session.java:937) ~[opensmpp-core-3.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.smpp.Session.send(Session.java:990) ~[opensmpp-core-3.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.smpp.Session.submit(Session.java:591) ~[opensmpp-core-3.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.example.mq.controller.SmsController.testMail(SmsController.java:45) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I looked at the source code of openSMPP to understand the reason, because the account binding failed, session will be closed; which will cause a exception when executing session.submit